# Hardware interrupt list

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, 16-bit

Is there any list of the hardware interrupts? i was coding a 16-bit app and i wanted to check some INTs but, i couldnt find anything usefull in google, can any1 provide me some docs about it? if possible, with details.

Im sorry if its not a valid request but, its the only place that suits this question i think

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for: [Ralf Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm)